# Find all documents where two conditions in subdocument are true in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to return all documents where conditions on subdocuments are true at the same time. So I got a subdocument (team) in a document (case). Each team subdocument has an array of members like below

Subdocument team 1

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d19"),
    "empId" : "1234",
    "funct" : "1. Assistant"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d17"),
    "empId" : "1235",
    "funct" : "1. Worker"
}
```

Subdocument team 2

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d19"),
    "empId" : "1235",
    "funct" : "1. Assistant"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d17"),
    "empId" : "1234",
    "funct" : "1. Worker"
}
```

Now I want to return all documents, which has a team member with employee id 1234, but only if the role in that document was 1. Assistant. So only the document should be return, which inclides subdocument 1, not the second. I tried some things, but fail to find the right point in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        "team":{
            $elemMatch:{
                "empId":"1234",
                "funct" : "1. Assistant"
            }
        }
    }
).pretty()
```

**Data Set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6409f9e152f06da2793ba7"),
    "team" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d19"),
            "empId" : "1234",
            "funct" : "1. Assistant"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d17"),
            "empId" : "1235",
            "funct" : "1. Worker"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6409f9e152f06da2793ba8"),
    "team" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d19"),
            "empId" : "1235",
            "funct" : "1. Assistant"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d17"),
            "empId" : "1234",
            "funct" : "1. Worker"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6409f9e152f06da2793ba7"),
    "team" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d19"),
            "empId" : "1234",
            "funct" : "1. Assistant"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2b506f725a6909789e4d17"),
            "empId" : "1235",
            "funct" : "1. Worker"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Easier than I thought. You know about a good tutorial or cheat sheet, to find useful queries?